# Factoring out a derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, factoring

Can the square of the derivative $(dy/d\xi)^2$ in the following expression

$$
\frac{dc}{d\xi} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\xi}\left(\frac{d y}{d \xi}\right)^2+\frac{2}{\xi +\kappa a}\left(\frac{d y}{d\xi}\right)^2
$$

be factored out like so:

$$
\frac{dc}{d\xi} = \left(\frac{d y}{d \xi}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\xi}+ \frac{2}{\xi +\kappa a}\right)?
$$

My intuition is telling me that this is not possible.

Comment: The term $\frac{d}{d\xi}$ in $\frac{d}{d\xi}\left(\frac{d y}{d \xi}\right)^2$ is not really a multiplying factor, so no. However, sometimes such things can be seen purely as a notation.

Comment: You may see it but with the factor at the left and considered as an operator : $$\frac{dc}{d\xi} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d}{d\xi}\right)+ \frac{2}{\xi +\kappa a}(\mathbb{1})\right)\left(\frac{d y}{d \xi}\right)^2$$

Comment: No. Consider $\frac{d}{dx} x^2 + x^2$.